# How to add a artifactory? i'm getting error with pod repo-art add command

Tags: ios, cocoapods, artifactory, podspec, jfrog-cli

I am trying to add a artifactory using below command

`pod repo-art add [artifactory name] "url"`

but i'm getting following error

`` [!] Error getting the index from Artifactory at: 'url' : undefined local variable or method `user_agent_argument' for #<Pod::Downloader::Http:0x00007f9d3faebdf0> ``

Please help!

Comment: We met this issue recently, and recalculate cocoapods repo index might help to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

try Remove the existing repos in ~ /. Cocoapods path

Answer (score 0):

You need to install cocoapods-art plugin to provision CocoaPods packages from Artifactory to the pod command-line tool. The very first thing you need to ensure is to install this plugin. It is a Ruby gem, and your machine should have the latest Ruby installed.  Install the gem cocoapods-art using the following command:

```
> gem install cocoapods-art
```

Then, you will need to add the specs of the Artifactory repository into your machine using

> `pod repo-art add <name> <url>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall cocoapods via gem. I had installed it by homebrew, and cocoa pods-art by gem which created some issues.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reinstall gem
you can try `gem install cocoapods-art --user-install` instead of  `gem install cocoapods-art`

"user install" the cocoapods-art and try `pod repo-art add [artifactory name] "url"`

It worked for me